# kendo scrollview as clientTemplate doesnt work when providing it a template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, scrollview

I am working on a page of a website using Kendo `ASP.NET MVC`.

What I need is a table with a detail row. Within that detail row, I require a Kendo ScrollView to display images.

When I attempt to use a template to format the `ScrollView` data, I encounter an error indicating that the template containing the `ScrollView` is invalid.

Is it that I cannot use nested templates for `ScrollViews`, or is there a way to achieve this?

```
<script id="showDefectDetails" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    @(Html.Kendo().ScrollView()
        .Name("scrollView_#=DefectID#")
        .ContentHeight("100%")
        .TemplateId("scrollview-template")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Custom()
            .Type("aspnetmvc-ajax")
            .Transport(transport => transport
            .Read(read => read.Action("DefectImage_Read", "InspectionData", new { defectId = "#=DefectID#" }))
            )
            .Schema(s => s.Data("Data").Total("Total"))
            .ServerPaging(true)
            .PageSize(1))
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:40vh; width:80vw" })
        .ToComponent()
        .ToClientTemplate()
    )
</script>

<script id="scrollview-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <p>#=data.DisplayName#</p>
</script>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the kendo MVC wrappers like:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ScrollView()
```

are processed on the server by Razor and coverted to javascript before the page is sent to the browser.

Kendo templates in turn are processed in the browser. I don't know what the "showDefectDetails" script looks like once the browser has it but it appears to have ended up invalid in the context of a template. You can use the browser tools to find and see what you have actually got.

I see that you have a templated piece of data here:

```
.Name("scrollView_#=DefectID#")
```

I doubt that will work as you hope because that would have been processed on the server before the page reached the browser.

My recommendation is that you create the scroll view using jquery plugin syntax instead of the Razor syntax in the template.